# How can I add more than 3 tags to a linkedIn post?

Tags: linkedin

I have recently written a LinkedIn post that I thought was worth having more than three tags, but when I tried to add them I got this:

[image]

The message isn't clear, does it mean:

- I can add 3 tags each time I update this post? (I tried, and no)
- There's a limit of 3 tags per post (then their wording is incorrect)
- I need to perform mysterious actions to be able to add more than 3 tags to a post

I googled around, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means you can have only 3 tags for a post. That means 3 tags per post.

[LinkedIn help page](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53873/~/adding-tags-to-your-long-form-post) says:

> You can add up to 3 tags to each long-form post.

Available tags include:

- Fields, such as Project Management
- Skills, such as Javascript
- Industries, such as Retail

For more information -> [Tagging Long-Form Posts - Overview](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53872/~/tagging-long-form-posts---overview)

> We don’t currently support the function of creating your own tags, and can’t take requests for additional tags.